# How do these queries execute?

Tags: sql, teradata

1

```
select c.c_name, a.n_name
from    retail.client c left join retail.area a
on  c.c_nationkey = a.n_nationkey
and a.n_name is null;
```

2.

```
select c.c_name, a.n_name
from    retail.client c left join retail.area a
on  c.c_nationkey = a.n_nationkey
where   a.n_name is null;
```

The following queries returns same number of rows.

when I do

```
    select c.c_name, a.n_name
    from    retail.client c left join retail.area a
    on  c.c_nationkey = a.n_nationkey
    and a.n_name is null
MiNUS
    select c.c_name, a.n_name
    from    retail.client c left join retail.area a
    on  c.c_nationkey = a.n_nationkey
    where   a.n_name is null
```

it returns 0 rows.
 so I think there must be some difference in the way they get executed.can any one explain. 
And I would be thankful If some one refers me execution order of t-sql statement. I am a beginner in Teradata sql.

Is there any article on the internet --explaining order of execution of sql statements in different types of databases. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess you have a typo error, because both are exactly same queries.

Comment: @jarlh The OP was asking about `explaining order of execution of sql statements in different types of databases` so the tags you have edited out might be important to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The first query has only a `JOIN`, the second has a `JOIN` and a `WHERE`.

Comment: @MTO, still asking for links etc.

Comment: both queries are same :)

Comment: EXPLAIN on the query you are trying to execute will give you a peek into 'how' the query is going to be executed.

EXPLAIN select c.c_name ..... ;

Answer (score 1):

Those queries will **not** return the same result.

Q1 returns **all** rows from `client` with `NULL` in `n_name`. When you `EXPLAIN` it you will see that the optimizer eliminated the join:

```
  1) First, we lock retail.c for read on a reserved RowHash to prevent
     global deadlock.
  2) Next, we lock retail.c for read.
  3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from retail.c by way of an
     all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 1
     (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of
     Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 1,536 rows (
     136,704 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.08 seconds.
  4) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.08 seconds.
```

In fact this is exactly the same as

```
select c.c_name, NULL S n_name
from    retail.client c
```

But Q2 returns only where `c_nationkey` doesn't exists in `n_nationkey`, i.e. this is similar to a `NOT EXISTS`. On the actaul data in this sample database there will be no row returned.

Regarding details on the logical execution of a SQL SELECT have a look at Itzik Ben-Gan's new articles on SQL Server:

[Logical Query Processing: What It Is And What It Means to You](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)

[Logical Query Processing: The FROM Clause and Joins](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-clause-and-joins)

Teradata is almost the same, just doesn't support CROSS/OUTER APPLY, but adds QUALIFY for filtering the result of an OLAP-Function:

FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - Windowed Aggregates/OLAP - QUALIFY - SELECT - ORDER BY

The `MINUS` query does **not** return zero rows, it returns the same as Q1, just as a `DISTINCT` result.

Comment: Please explain this on (got doubt on this one)
'SELECT 
*
FROM  S1DTPLCS.T5DS_ACCOUNT_PARTY AS ACCTPARTY
INNER JOIN 
S1DTPLCS.T5DS_PART_INFO as PARTINFO
ON ACCTPARTY.CUST_NO_RM = PARTINFO.CUST_NO_RM
WHERE ACCTPARTY.PRI_SEC_CD = 'PRI'

MINUS
SELECT 
*
FROM  S1DTPLCS.T5DS_ACCOUNT_PARTY AS ACCTPARTY
INNER JOIN 
S1DTPLCS.T5DS_PART_INFO as PARTINFO
ON ACCTPARTY.CUST_NO_RM = PARTINFO.CUST_NO_RM
AND ACCTPARTY.PRI_SEC_CD = 'PRI';'

Comment: @PolukantiGouthamkrishna: Those queries do exactly the same, for Inner Joins the placement of search-conditions (ON vs. WHERE) doesn't matter. So you return a result set and subtract exactly the same result set -> empty result